# ReflectionException error when setting up my own library in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am a Laravel newbie. I'm following a tutorial where someone sets up a custom library to verify forms. My directory structure is setup like this:

```
Lara
----->app----->Acme----->Services
                   ----->Validators
----->bootstrap
----->public
----->vendor
```

I get an error: `ReflectionException Class Acme\Services\TasksValidator does not exist`

I suspect it's in my TaskController which starts like this:

```
<?php
use \Acme\Services\TaskCreatorService;

class TasksController extends BaseController{
        protected $taskCreator;

        public function __construct(TaskCreatorService $taskCreator){
            $this->taskCreator = $taskCreator;

        }

        public function index(){
        $tasks = Task::with('user')->get();
        $users = User::lists('username', 'id');
```

What am I doing wrong? I've added the following in my composer.json under autoload

```
        "psr-0":{
            "Acme":"app/"
        }
```

I've also run: `composer dump-autoload -o`

My TaskCreatorService file begins like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Services;

use Acme\Validators\TaskValidator;
use Acme\Validators\ValidationException;
use Task;

class TaskCreatorService{
    protected $validator;
```

Comment: Where are you using TasksValidator at? Is that in TaskCreatorService?

Comment: @cillosis: Yes it's used in TaskCreatorService

Comment: Can you show that code? Or link to the tutorial that has it?

Comment: @cillosis: I'm following the Laracast video tutorials. Don't know if the code is available online. I've been typing it as I follow along

Comment: The error says `Acme\Services\TasksValidator` is missing, and in the code you updated with, you are doing a `use` on `Acme\Validators\TaskValidator`. So you are either using the wrong one, calling it with the wrong name, or the issue lies inside `Acme\Validators\TaskValidator`. The other thing to look at is you used `TaskValidator` with a singular "task", and the other one has plural "tasks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring

```
use Acme\Validators\TaskValidator;
```

And using in your class:

```
\Acme\Services\TasksValidator (with an S)
```